# New Interface Collapsing Label List

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, user-interface

I like everything about the new interface except how the label list is collapsed, see below.

[image]

Can this option be disabled? I tried to find it in the settings but did not recognize anything listed as taking on that role.

Answer (score 2):

to disable it all you need to do is to click on those 3 lines:

[image]